Key pressed speed
I need help with my script below. In the simulation part of the W and S keys, it is very slow, although I have set the speed to 1ms it is being pressed very slowly. I set it to 1 millisecond, it seems like the keys are being pressed every 1 second, I wanted to make it faster, can anyone help me? I just want him to press the keys at the exact speed I set.
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading
import os
import time
import pygame
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener
import atexit
import random

# Inicializa o pygame para tocar os sons
pygame.mixer.init()

# Sons
som_macro = pygame.mixer.Sound('start.wav')  # Som para iniciar/parar o macro
som_imagem_y = pygame.mixer.Sound('stop.wav')  # Som para quando a imagem Y for detectada

# Variáveis globais
macro_rodando = False
diretorio_imagem_y = None
diretorio_imagem_x = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "imagemX.png")  # Caminho da imagem X no diretório do script
teclas_alternancia = ['w', 's']  # Teclas para alternar
botao_imagem_x = '4'  # Botão para pressionar quando a imagem X for detectada
tempo_alternancia = 0.001  # Tempo de alternância em segundos (inicialmente 1 ms)

# Inicializa o controlador de teclado
controlador = Controller()
listener = None

# Função para pressionar e soltar uma tecla
def pressionar_tecla(tecla):
    controlador.press(tecla)
    controlador.release(tecla)

# Função para detectar a imagem na tela
def detectar_imagem(diretorio):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(diretorio):
            raise ValueError(f"Arquivo de imagem não encontrado: {diretorio}")
        diretorio = os.path.normpath(diretorio)
        imagem_modelo = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(diretorio, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        if imagem_modelo is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Não foi possível carregar a imagem: {diretorio}")
        tela = pyautogui.screenshot()
        tela = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(tela), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        resultado = cv2.matchTemplate(tela, imagem_modelo, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        _, max_valor, _, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(resultado)
        return max_valor > 0.8
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erro ao detectar a imagem: {e}")
        return False

# Função da macro
def executar_macro():
    global macro_rodando, tempo_alternancia
    ultimo_tecla = None
    tempo_alternancia *= 0.1  # Reduz o tempo de alternância para acelerar o processo
    ultimo_tempo = time.perf_counter()

    while macro_rodando:
        if diretorio_imagem_y and detectar_imagem(diretorio_imagem_y):
            print("Imagem Y detectada. Parando a macro.")
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(som_imagem_y)
            macro_rodando = False
            break
        if detectar_imagem(diretorio_imagem_x):
            print(f"Imagem X detectada. Clicando {botao_imagem_x}.")
            pressionar_tecla(botao_imagem_x)
        tempo_atual = time.perf_counter()
        if tempo_atual - ultimo_tempo >= tempo_alternancia:
            # Escolhe uma tecla aleatória, diferente da última tecla pressionada
            teclas_disponiveis = [tecla for tecla in teclas_alternancia if tecla != ultimo_tecla]
            if teclas_disponiveis:
                tecla_atual = random.choice(teclas_disponiveis)
                pressionar_tecla(tecla_atual)
                ultimo_tecla = tecla_atual
            ultimo_tempo = tempo_atual

# Função para iniciar/parar a macro
def toggle_macro():
    global macro_rodando
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(som_macro)
    if macro_rodando:
        print("Parando macro.")
        macro_rodando = False
    else:
        print("Iniciando macro.")
        macro_rodando = True
        threading.Thread(target=executar_macro).start()

# Função para selecionar o diretório da imagem Y
def selecionar_imagem_y():
    global diretorio_imagem_y
    diretorio_imagem_y = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Selecione a imagem Y")
    if diretorio_imagem_y:
        diretorio_imagem_y = os.path.abspath(diretorio_imagem_y)
        print(f"Imagem Y selecionada: {diretorio_imagem_y}")

# Função para selecionar o diretório da imagem X
def selecionar_imagem_x():
    global diretorio_imagem_x
    diretorio_imagem_x = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Selecione a imagem X")
    if diretorio_imagem_x:
        diretorio_imagem_x = os.path.abspath(diretorio_imagem_x)
        print(f"Imagem X selecionada: {diretorio_imagem_x}")

# Função para selecionar o diretório da imagem X
def selecionar_imagem_x():
    global diretorio_imagem_x
    diretorio_imagem_x = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Selecione a imagem X")
    if diretorio_imagem_x:
        diretorio_imagem_x = os.path.abspath(diretorio_imagem_x)
        print(f"Imagem X selecionada: {diretorio_imagem_x}")

# Função para configurar as teclas e o botão
def configurar():
    def salvar_configuracoes():
        global teclas_alternancia, botao_imagem_x, tempo_alternancia
        teclas_alternancia = [tecla.strip() for tecla in entrada_teclas_alternancia.get().split(',')]
        botao_imagem_x = entrada_botao.get().strip()
        try:
            tempo_alternancia = float(entrada_tempo.get().strip())
        except ValueError:
            print("Valor inválido para tempo de alternância. Usando o valor padrão.")
            tempo_alternancia = 0.001
        print(f"Configurações atualizadas: Teclas Alternância: {teclas_alternancia}, Botão Imagem X: {botao_imagem_x}, Tempo de Alternância: {tempo_alternancia} segundos")
        configuracoes_window.destroy()

    configuracoes_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    configuracoes_window.title("Configurações")
    configuracoes_window.configure(bg='#6A0D91')
    configuracoes_window.attributes('-topmost', True)
    configuracoes_window.resizable(False, False)

    # Remove o tamanho fixo para permitir ajuste automático
    configuracoes_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    configuracoes_window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
    configuracoes_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    configuracoes_window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    configuracoes_window.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    configuracoes_window.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

    label_teclas_alternancia = tk.Label(configuracoes_window, text="Teclas Alternância (separadas por vírgula e espaço):", bg='#6A0D91', fg='white')
    label_teclas_alternancia.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
    entrada_teclas_alternancia = tk.Entry(configuracoes_window)
    entrada_teclas_alternancia.insert(0, ', '.join(teclas_alternancia))
    entrada_teclas_alternancia.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="ew")

    label_botao = tk.Label(configuracoes_window, text="Botão Imagem X:", bg='#6A0D91', fg='white')
    label_botao.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
    entrada_botao = tk.Entry(configuracoes_window)
    entrada_botao.insert(0, botao_imagem_x)
    entrada_botao.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="ew")

    label_tempo = tk.Label(configuracoes_window, text="Tempo de Alternância (em segundos):", bg='#6A0D91', fg='white')
    label_tempo.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
    entrada_tempo = tk.Entry(configuracoes_window)
    entrada_tempo.insert(0, str(tempo_alternancia))
    entrada_tempo.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="ew")

    botao_salvar = tk.Button(configuracoes_window, text="Salvar Configurações", command=salvar_configuracoes, bg='#4B0082', fg='white')
    botao_salvar.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

# Função para escutar teclas
def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.f8:
        toggle_macro()

# Função para encerrar o programa limpo
def cleanup():
    global listener
    if listener:
        listener.stop()
    pygame.mixer.quit()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Programa encerrado corretamente.")

# GUI principal
def criar_gui():
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Macro de Imagens")
    
    # Configura a cor de fundo e outras propriedades
    root.configure(bg='#6A0D91')  # Cor de fundo roxa
    
    # Força a janela a ficar sempre no topo
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    
    # Impede o redimensionamento da janela
    root.resizable(False, False)
    
    # Configura o estilo dos widgets
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Selecione a Imagem Y para parar a macro:", bg='#6A0D91', fg='white', font=('Arial', 12))
    label.pack(pady=10)

    botao_selecionar_x = tk.Button(root, text="Selecionar Imagem X", command=selecionar_imagem_x, bg='#4B0082', fg='white', font=('Arial', 12))
    botao_selecionar_x.pack(pady=10)
    
    botao_selecionar_y = tk.Button(root, text="Selecionar Imagem Y", command=selecionar_imagem_y, bg='#4B0082', fg='white', font=('Arial', 12))
    botao_selecionar_y.pack(pady=10)
    
    botao_configurar = tk.Button(root, text="Configurar Teclas e Botão", command=configurar, bg='#4B0082', fg='white', font=('Arial', 12))
    botao_configurar.pack(pady=10)
    
    root.mainloop()

# Inicia o listener de teclas
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

# Inicia a interface gráfica
criar_gui()

# Registra a função de limpeza para ser chamada ao sair
atexit.register(cleanup)

The keys feel like they are being pressed in 1 second, even though I set it to 1 millisecond

The key pressing is not the problem.  You are copying the ENTIRE desktop into a memory bitmap.  For a full HD desktop, that's 8 megabytes, and the path reading from graphics memory is not highly optimized.  Then, you are asking OpenCV to search through that entire bitmap to find your match.  That has to be done one pixel at a time, 2 million times.  If you know EXACTLY where your image will be, reduce the screenshot size.

Did you do any instrumentation to see what was taking all the time?

I didn't it. Could you help me how can I do this?

There's no magic here.  Your whole concept is flawed.  Even IF you could type 1,000 characters a second, your screen only refreshes 60 times a second, so any string less than 16 characters long will appear instantly.  As I said, if you know where your target image will appear, you can limit screenshot to that rectangle.  If not, then what you ask cannot be done.
